# Reloading the collectionView after delete

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase. My code works but my issue is when I press the accept button, I want that index to be deleted from the collectionView and I want the table to reload right away right after. I can't use the slide to delete because I need it for another function.

[image]

This is in my cell class thats why I did not use `self.` to call the collectionView. This function is being called by a `addTarget()` method. I'm thinking maybe passing an indexPath as a parameter, but I don't know how to pass an indexPath.item as a parameter and also how to pass a parameter inside an addTarget() method.

```
func handleAccept(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("button pressed")
        guard let artId = art?.artId else {return}
        let approvedRef = 
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("approved_art")
        approvedRef.updateChildValues([artId: 1])
        let pendingRef = 
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("pending_art").child("\(artId)")
        pendingRef.removeValue { (error, ref) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }
            let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            let pendingArtCollectionViewController = 
    PendingArtsCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                pendingArtCollectionViewController.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you just need the indexpath of the corresponding row of the tableview ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass indexpath as argument, you can get the indexpath of the tableView in button action with the following code :

```
func handleAccept(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let center = sender.center
            let rootViewPoint = sender.superview!!.convert(center!, to: self.myTableView)
            let currentIndexpath = myTableView.indexPathForRow(at: rootViewPoint)
    }
```